# ListViewItem implicitly adds ListViewSubItem

Tags: c#, listview

Suppose I build `ListView` with following code:

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();
item1.Text = "item1";
item1.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item1, "subitem1"));
item1.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item1, "subitem2"));
listView1.Items.Add(item1);
```

But in fact it will create 3 `ListViewSubItem`s like this:

```
ListViewItem 
     |
     -------------------------------------
     |                  |                |
ListViewSubItem  ListViewSubItem  ListViewSubItem
 (Text=item1)    (Text=subitem1)  (Text=subitem2)
```

In my real program I use custom subitems derived from `ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem` and `OwnerDraw = true`

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();
CustomListViewSubItem subitem1 = new CustomListViewSubItem(item1, "subitem1");
CustomListViewSubItem subitem1 = new CustomListViewSubItem(item1, "subitem1");
listView1.Items.Add(item1);
```

and the above behavior breaks all the logic while casting in `DrawSubItems` event:

```
private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = e.Item;
    ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subitem = item.SubItems[e.ColumnIndex];
    CustomListViewSubItem customsubitem = (CustomListViewSubItem)subitem; // <- System.InvalidCastException here
    ...
}
```

Sure it will fail only for first subitem which in fact is item but that's not I want. How can I avoid this behavior and create only 2 subitems I need?

Comment: Have you checked if maybe when instantiating new `ListViewItem`  the SubItems list is empty? Maybe it just adds one standard subitem when initialized?

Comment: Check the `ListViewItem` documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=vs.110).aspx It says the first item is always the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but may work:
By calling `listView.SubItems` on empty collection it automatically adds one "default" element. My advise would be to remove first element after adding your element like:

```
listView.SubItems.Add(new MeListViewSubItem( ... ) );
listView.SubItems.RemoveAt(0);
```

From [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListViewItem.cs,5fff72bdbef865c1):

```
    /// <include file='doc\ListViewItem.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="ListViewItem.SubItems"]/*' />
    /// <devdoc>
    ///    <para>[To be supplied.]</para>
    /// </devdoc>
    [
    SRCategory(SR.CatData),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden),        
    SRDescription(SR.ListViewItemSubItemsDescr),
    Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ListViewSubItemCollectionEditor, " + AssemblyRef.SystemDesign,typeof(UITypeEditor)),
    ]
    public ListViewSubItemCollection SubItems {
        get {
            if (SubItemCount == 0) {
                subItems = new ListViewSubItem[1];
                subItems[0] = new ListViewSubItem(this, string.Empty);                        
                SubItemCount = 1;
            }

            if (listViewSubItemCollection == null) {
                listViewSubItemCollection = new ListViewSubItemCollection(this);
            }
            return listViewSubItemCollection;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I see now where the problem is, thank you. I've came from C++ world and it looks I never get used to the lack of logic and confusions in C#.